# Why can decoder-only transformers be so good at machine translation?

Tags: transformer, machine-translation, encoder-decoder

In my understanding encoder-decoder transformers for translation are trained with sentence or text pairs. How can it be explained in simple (high-level) terms that decoder-only transformers (e.g. GPT) are so [good at machine translation](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2302.09210.pdf), even though they are not trained on sentence or text pairs but only on unrelated multilingual training data? Why can decoder-only transformers do without it? Or did I get something wrong?

Are the documents in the training data containing accidentally sentence pairs near each other possibly enough?

Answer (score 1):

Docoder-only transformers are also trained on text pairs. You first pre-train on general text data. After that you fine tune with a standard two language dataset containing example translations.

The trick is that you concatenate the source and the target sentence, you put a special separator token, and you treat the task as language modelling, i.e. you ask the model to predict the next word one-by-one.

Input: ["Good", "morning", "everyone", "<SEP>", "Guten", "Morgen", "zusammen", "<END>".]
Decoder output: [$z_1, z_2, z_3, z_4, z_5, z_6, z_7, z_8$]
You then compute the loss by considering only the outputs from $z_5$ to $z_8$.